# How to change ui5 theme in component-based app of HCP WebIDE?

Tags: sapui5, sap-cloud-platform

When I run webide project in UI5, it use sap_bluecrystal theme([webapp/resources/sap/ui/core/themes/sap_bluecrystal/library.css](http://webapp/resources/sap/ui/core/themes/sap_bluecrystal/library.css)), but when I register my project to Fiori Launchpad of Portal Service, the theme changed to sap_belize.([resources/sap/fiori/themes/sap_belize/library.css?version=1.44.11&sap-ui-dist-version=1.44.11](http://resources/sap/fiori/themes/sap_belize/library.css?version=1.44.11&sap-ui-dist-version=1.44.11))

I want the theme to be consistent, I changed the `manifest.json` but it did not work:

```
"sap.ui": {
    "supportedThemes": [
        "sap_belize"
    ]
}
```

And in `Project Settings -> SAPUI5`, it can only change UI5 versions, not theme.

Comment: Actually, it is mentioned in ui5 doc: https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/e9fc648661d84ed89360bbec3ae02611.html, but the `component-based app` template confused me. Thanks to @loki, I located that index html file in `test/flpSandbox.html`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you mentioning the theme while bootstrapping as follows:

```
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" 
            src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"         
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal" ... > </script>
```

Maybe this can help it become consistent.

Comment: Thank you ! I found that in `flpSandbox.html`!

Comment: @Tina          Thank you for accepting. It is the first answer of mine which got accepted. I am new to SAPUI5 and seeing my answer was somewhat correct gave me a bit confidence. Thank you for the boost.

Answer (score 2):

You can even force the app to load the theme with this code

```
sap.ui.getCore().applyTheme("sap_belize");
```

Initialise this either in component.js or the initial view onInit method.